# Como modificar o valor dos campos de uma coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Estou com uma dúvida simples mas que eu não consegui encontrar solução.

Do mesmo modo que eu posso quando uso `select` trazer uma coluna vazia usando `select a.x,NULL as y,a.z from DADOS a`, como eu posso fazer com que uma coluna invés de ter apenas valores `NULL`, sejam preenchidos com alguma palavra de minha escola?

Comment: Encontrou o que procurava? Não deixe de selecionar a pergunta que acha correta

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar `CASE` no `select`:

```
select a.x,
       NULL as y,
       CASE a.z 
           WHEN NULL THEN 'Vazio'
           ELSE a.z
       END as c          

from DADOS a
```

Comment: Obrigado, Eduardo.

Answer (score 1):

Em MySQL você pode usar a função [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html), Da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT IFNULL(UnitsOnOrder,0))
FROM Products
```

Quando o campo UnitsOnOrder for null o valor será alterado para 0. IFNULL pode receber vários tipos de parâmetros entre eles inteiros e strings.

Caso o campo seja uma string onde os valores possam conter tanto null quanto Empty você pode usar a expressão.

```
SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL or field1 = '', 'empty', field1) as field1 
from tablename
```

Para outros banco de dados existe funções similares que pode ser vistas [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).